# How to use Job Scheduler for weekly updates

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

In my app, I am trying to display the users who have most points in a weekly basis. I came to know that this can be done using Job Scheduler.

As I am not able to find a proper way to use Job Scheduler for weekly updates, I have zero idea how to implement this for my agenda.

Please help me solve.

Comment: JobInfo.Builder has a method 'setPeriodic' that can be used to make the job recur at the specified interval. Read more on the official Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setPeriodic(long)) page.

Comment: So, I should give the interval in milliseconds for one week?